# can I send additional variables through form post in PHP?

Tags: php

I have mysql table `members` with columns `id`, `user`, `password`, and `verified`

When a user logs in, using user and password (compared against members-db) they are presented with a form.  The form gathers info to be manually checked by an admin.
Upon submitting the form, it will send an email to admin with all the details to manually confirm.

The problem that I am hitting is that admin wants the email to contain a link that will enable him to update the verified field in members table upon clicking.  I need to send a previously stored variable with the form to do so.  That way I have a link to the members table.

For example, If I store $user_id as the id of whichever row I need to update, and I could send it forward with the form, then I could just use the UPDATE feature WHERE id = $user_id

Here is my form ...

```
<form method="post" name="verify_form" action="../includes/verify.php">
Website for Online Verification: <input type="text" name="webpage" id="webpage" /><br />
Identification Number: <input type="text" name="number" id="number" /><br />
Expiration Date: <input type="text" name="expire" id="expire" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Verify Me!" onclick="return vformhash(this.form, this.form.webpage, this.form.number, this.form.expire);" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />
</form>
```

Is there a  way to send my previously captured $user_id to the verify.php page when user submits?

Comment: you could use hidden form fields. haven't thought about any security impact though. e.g. http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm

Comment: @dagon I read it.  Looks to confirm that I posted an excellent question.  But as it says down at the end, sometimes people are too pretentious to receive your questions. Don't despair.  Best advice on there.  Thanks again buddy. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" >
```

Comment: This is not a good method to send it through hidden field but still if you want to do it then encode your user_id before passing to the hidden field.and decode it when you get on the form

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<input type='hidden' name='user' value=<?php echo $user_id; ?>>
```

inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could send it in url like

```
 $url = "verify.php?user_id=" . $ user_id;
```

And access it in verify.php page by

```
 $ user_id = $_GET ['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden fields: `<input type="hidden"...`.

If the information is sensitive, you should not put it in those hidden fields, but rather store it in the session or otherwise on your server. You can then use a hidden field to store a key that you can use to find those values again later.

If you would use regular session variables, without a key in the form, you might get the issue of finding the wrong value if the user has multiple forms open in multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Change your for tag to pass the ID as a GET param :

```
action="../includes/verify.php?user_id=123"
```

-or-

Add a hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="123" />
```

You will be able to access this value with either `$_GET['user_id']` for option #1, or `$_POST['user_id']` for option #2 within your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, save their ID in a session value such as `$_SESSION["userID"]`. Then in verify.php you can access `$_SESSION["userID"]`.  It's cleaner than passing the ID back and forth as parameters.